# Where in the standard is forwarding to a base class required in these situations?

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

Maybe even better is: Why does the standard require forwarding to a base class in these situations? (yeah yeah yeah -  Why? - Because.)

```
class B1 {
public:
    virtual void f()=0;
};
class B2 {
public:
    virtual void f(){}
};
class D : public B1,public B2{
};
class D2 : public B1,public B2{
public:
    using B2::f;
};
class D3 : public B1,public B2{
public:
    void f(){
        B2::f();
    }
};
D d;
D2 d2;
D3 d3;
```

MS gives:

```
sourceFile.cpp
sourceFile.cpp(24) : error C2259: 'D' : cannot instantiate abstract class
        due to following members:
        'void B1::f(void)' : is abstract
        sourceFile.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'B1::f'
sourceFile.cpp(25) : error C2259: 'D2' : cannot instantiate abstract class
        due to following members:
        'void B1::f(void)' : is abstract
        sourceFile.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'B
```

and similarly for the MS compiler.

I **might** buy the first case,D. But in D2 - f is **unambiguously** defined by the using declaration, why is that not enough for the compiler to be required to fill out the vtable?

Where in the standard is this situation defined?

**added in reponse to answer**

Regarding the answer below that I have accepted:

Why does this not seem an error in the spec? - If one has an inheritance hierarchy with a series of non virtual f()'s, the use of which in derived classes being determined by using statements, and one changes the decl of f in a base class to virtual then that can change which f is called in derived classes with using statements to pick their f. It is a c++ "gotcha"of which I was unaware. It may be part of the language but such "action at a distance" makes me uneasy and to me seems a violation of some sort of correctness / maintenance principle (that I can't quite formulate right now).

But I can give an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;


namespace NonVirtual_f{

class C0 {
public:
    void f(){cout<<"C0::f()"<<'\n';}
};

class C1 : public C0{
public:
    void f(){cout<<"C1::f()"<<'\n';}
};

class C2 : public virtual C1{
public:
    void f(){cout<<"C2::f()"<<'\n';}
};

class D3 : public virtual C1, public C2{
public:
    using C1::f;
};


}//namespace NonVirtual_f

namespace Virtual_f{


class C0 {
public:
    virtual void f(){cout<<"C0::f()"<<'\n';}
};

class C1 : public C0{
public:
    void f(){cout<<"C1::f()"<<'\n';}
};

class C2 : public virtual C1{
public:
    void f(){cout<<"C2::f()"<<'\n';}
};

class D3 : public virtual C1, public C2{
public:
    using C1::f;
};



}//namespace Virtual_f




int main(int argc,const char* const*argv){

    NonVirtual_f::D3 nv3;
    nv3.f();

    Virtual_f::D3 v3;
    v3.f();

    return 0;    
}
```

Whence the output:

```
C1::f()
C2::f()
```

All that is changed is the virtualness of f in C0. In particular once the non-virtualness of f in a base class is chosen, it cannot be changed without maintenance issues if some derived class (that in general one ***can't*** know about) has "overridden" as in the example immediately above.

If you counter with "Well, do not override that way in the NonVirtual case", I agree it is bad practice but this seems more than just that. To me the language should:

not allow the using in NonVirtual::D3 (not possible currently as there may be other overloaded f's to bring in [unless using allowed a signature in the function case])

*or*

disallow using statements of functions completely and force forwarding

*or*

have using actually override in all cases

*or*

allow some syntactical declarative for functions (essentially a function using) like:

```
void f(*signature*) = C2::f;
```

What, exactly, am I missing here? 
Can someone come up with a scenario that clarifies the "why" of this choice in the standard?

Comment: FYI:  the posted errors are from Visual C++ :-)

Comment: EDG
"sourceFile.cpp", line 24: error: 
          object of abstract class type "D" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "B1::f" has no overrider
  D d;
    ^

"sourceFile.cpp", line 25: error: 
          object of abstract class type "D2" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "B1::f" has no overrider
  D2 d2;
     ^

Comment: You may already know this, but just as an FYI, if you had put f() = 0 in a virtual base class of B1 and B2, then D would work. See sister class delegation: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard says in §10.3/2:

> The rules for member lookup (10.2) are used to determine the final overrider for a virtual function in the scope of a derived class but ignoring names introduced by *using-declarations*.

So, even though you use `using B2::f;` to bring `B2::f()` into the derived class, it is not considered to override `B1::f()`.

Thus, `D2` is abstract because of §10.4/4:

> A class is abstract if it contains or inherits at least one pure virtual function for which the final overrider is pure virtual.

Comment: And why does this not seem an error in the spec? - If one has an inheritance hierarchy with a series of non virtual f()'s, the use of which in derived classes being determined by using statements, and one changes the decl of   f   in a base class to virtual then that can change which f is called in derived classes with using statements to pick their f. It is a c++ "gotcha"of which I was unaware. It may be part of the language but such "action at a distance" makes me uneasy and to me seems a violation of some sort of correctness/maintenance principle (that I can't quite formulate right now)